# Double.Parse not giving correct result

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying this in two application; a console application and a web application.

In the console app when I try `Double.Parse("0.5")` it gives 0.5 or `Double.Parse(".5")` gives 0.5

But in the web application `Double.Parse("0.5")` gives 5.0 and `Double.Parse(".5")` gives exception

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Can any one tell how can resolve the issue in web app?

Comment: Post the exact code you're using. It shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Oded in the web app it is treating the `.` as a thousand separator.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should provide culture information otherwise it uses the culture info from the currently running thread. Try this instead:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // or whatever you prefer
double result = double.Parse(".5", cultureInfo);
```

Comment: Dang, was gonna write that but saw your answer. Precise and to the point. nice!

Comment: Well, I clicked on Accept button immediately after(may be a milli second delay :p) it worked but SO asked me to wait for 3 minutes :(

Comment: @marc_s The site enforces a minimum time before accepting answers, to encourage users to wait a bit in case a better answer is posted.  Seems to be 15 minutes.